# Bodies do not collide

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

i have set 2 bodies, a world with gravity,a tick method with step,and all the bodies are moving just fine,and i can apply forces on them, gravity is also working.

but no collision.
when body1 hit the ground he just go out of screen and not hit it and jump like a real ball.
when body1 hit body2 the just continue movement as nothing was happen.

the bodies have shape ,the world have edges, but no collision.
what am i missing here  ?

here are some functions that i call from the init :

```
- (void)addBoxBodyForSprite:(CCSprite *)sprite {

    b2BodyDef spriteBodyDef;
    spriteBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    spriteBodyDef.position.Set(sprite.position.x/PTM_RATIO,sprite.position.y/PTM_RATIO);
    spriteBodyDef.userData = sprite;
    spriteBody = world->CreateBody(&spriteBodyDef);

    b2PolygonShape spriteShape;
    spriteShape.SetAsBox(sprite.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO/2,sprite.contentSize.height/PTM_RATIO/2);
    b2FixtureDef spriteShapeDef;
    spriteShapeDef.shape = &spriteShape;
    spriteShapeDef.density = 10.0;
    spriteShapeDef.isSensor = true;
    spriteBody->CreateFixture(&spriteShapeDef);

}


-(void)worldEdge
{
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
    groundBodyDef.position.Set(0,0);
    b2Body *groundBody = world->CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);
    b2PolygonShape groundBox;
    b2FixtureDef boxShapeDef;
    boxShapeDef.shape = &groundBox;
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, 0));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(0, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, 0));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
}




-(void)tick:(ccTime) dt
{


    world->Step(dt,10,10);
    for(b2Body *b=world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) 
    {
        if(b->GetUserData() !=NULL )
           {
               CCSprite *sprite=(CCSprite *) b->GetUserData();//every b of the world will be update his position
               sprite.position=ccp( b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO  ) ;
               sprite.rotation=-1*CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle());
           }

    }
```

everything is moving allright but no collision ever.

Comment: If one of the shapes is a sensor there will be no collision reaction.

Comment: Yeah but your contact listener can still detect contacts.

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem is this line:

```
spriteShapeDef.isSensor = true;
```

In box2d, when you set an **fixture** as a sensor, it will not collide with other fixtures.